Opentelemetry print console logs in json format
I am trying to print opentelemetry logs in json format to stdout/console in spring boot 3.3.4. And the latest log I got is like below
17:27:23.658 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= GET "/ping", parameters={}
17:27:23.675 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= Mapped to io.opentelemetry.example.graal.Controller#ping()
17:27:23.691 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
17:27:23.692 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= Writing ["pong"]
17:27:23.696 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= Completed 200 OK

I have tried many different parameters and env variables. When I set OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=console I got below log
2024-10-12T16:29:37.044Z DEBUG 'Writing ["pong"]' : f171ab68e6a9745eb2a670cb044d393a a5d868137585c4b9 [scopeInfo: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:] {code.filepath="LogFormatUtils.java", code.function="traceDebug", code.lineno=120, code.namespace="org.springframework.core.log.LogFormatUtils", thread.name="http-nio-8080-exec-1"}
17:29:37.048 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags= Completed 200 OK

f171ab68e6a9745eb2a670cb044d393a look like trace id, but I am not sure. below is my build.gradle.kts
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.10.3"
}

description = "OpenTelemetry Example for Spring native images"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES))
    implementation(platform("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-bom:2.8.0"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("com.h2database:h2")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.contrib:opentelemetry-samplers:1.39.0-alpha")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-logback-mdc-1.0:2.8.0-alpha")
}

below logback.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="OpenTelemetry"
              class="io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.logback.appender.v1_0.OpenTelemetryAppender">
        <captureExperimentalAttributes>true</captureExperimentalAttributes>
        <captureKeyValuePairAttributes>true</captureKeyValuePairAttributes>
        <captureCodeAttributes>true</captureCodeAttributes>
        <captureMarkerAttribute>true</captureMarkerAttribute>
        <captureMdcAttributes>*</captureMdcAttributes>
        <numLogsCapturedBeforeOtelInstall>1</numLogsCapturedBeforeOtelInstall>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} trace_id=%X{trace_id} span_id=%X{span_id} trace_flags=%X{trace_flags} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="OpenTelemetry"/>
    </root>
</configuration>

also here is my honeycomb.io parameters which is necessary for sending the data to HC
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=https://api.honeycomb.io;
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_HEADERS=x-honeycomb-team=XXXXX;
OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=console

So I can see the OTEL/OTLP entries in HC dashboard, meaning my app is sending the data. My main target is to print these to console in a structured(JSON) way. Anyone know how ?
Just for extra information, I did this in C# last week with an exporter https://stackoverflow.com/a/79055614/175554 and here is a full reproducer for spring boot java project https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/opentelemetry-native
EDIT 1: I tested logstash it generates json debug log, but it does not really print span id and trace id in KV format, more details here
